# PHP composer generate composer.lock file from packages already installed in vender

Tags: php, composer-php

I inherited a legacy code base where a previous developer did not commit the `composer.lock` file to version control, but instead committed all the packages in `vendor`. I know.

I have the `composer.json`, but it appears incomplete as it only has `require-dev`. Here's the complete `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.3.*",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.*",
        "phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor": "2.*"
    }
}
```

Can composer generate a composer.lock file from the packages already installed in vendor without updating those packages? When I run `composer install`, a lock file is created, but the packages are updated to their most recent versions instead of maintaining the version already installed.

Comment: There is no such functionality in Composer, neither a plugin to do this. Do you have file `vendor/composer/installed.json` in the repository? That would be the best way to recreate `require` in `composer.json`.

Answer (score 0):

run `composer update --lock` will only updates the lock file hash to suppress warning about the lock file being out of date without upgrade your packages.

reference: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update-u